# saveorupdate in Hibernate not working using @generated value in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, annotations

I have a problem with saveOrUpdate() function in hibernate.
I am using Oracle database. I need to insert a row with an auto generated primary key. I have configured this id in hibernate annotations as follows,

**Model.java**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column (name = "blush_id")
private Integer blsId;
```

But while executing the insert query, the id alone is getting generated. The saveOrUpdate method is not executed.

**DAO.java**

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
} 
public void executeSaveOrUpdate(Object obj){            
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(obj);//id generation occurs but the saveOrUpdate(obj) method is not executed
}
```

There is no error or exception thrown, but the insert query not executing (instead sequence is generated as in the 2nd line of console), control going to its next process.

### Console:

```
16:41:55,928 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select category0_.cat_nbr as cat1_2_, category0_.added_by_name as added2_2_, category0_.added_ts as added3_2_, category0_.cat_dsc as cat4_2_, category0_.last_updt_by_name as last5_2_, category0_.last_updt_ts as last6_2_, category0_.mdse_grp_dsc as mdse7_2_, category0_.mdse_grp_nbr as mdse8_2_ from cvs_category_admin category0_ order by category0_.cat_nbr
16:41:56,037 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual
16:41:56,084 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select blushrules0_.blush_id as blush1_1_, blushrules0_.added_by_name as added2_1_, blushrules0_.added_ts as added3_1_, blushrules0_.blush_item_type as blush4_1_, blushrules0_.cat_nbr as cat5_1_, blushrules0_.subcat_nbr as subcat12_1_, blushrules0_.is_active as is6_1_, blushrules0_.is_added as is7_1_, blushrules0_.last_updt_by_name as last8_1_, blushrules0_.last_updt_ts as last9_1_, blushrules0_.sku_nbr as sku10_1_, blushrules0_.status as status1_ from blush_admin_rules blushrules0_ where blushrules0_.status='A'
```

Please help me on this issue..

Comment: why do you say "id is not generated" ? do you have an error message or some logs explicitly showing that ? You need to provide more details.

Comment: @ben75 I have edited the question, please do tell me if anything else has to be added.

Comment: why do you say "the insert query not executing" ? because you don't see the insert log ? The insert is executed at commit time. So it would be interesting to see how you configure your transactions.

Comment: @ben75 There is no new entry in my table, hence I said that the insert statement is not getting executed.

Comment: The insert is executed at commit time. So it would be interesting to see how you configure your transactions.

Comment: @ben75 Yes it was a problem of committing the transaction. Thank you my problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem of committing to the transaction, especially in the case of multiple queries.

Answer (score -1):

You also need to flush your session. Add the following to the saveupdate statement.

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush()
```